# Computing slope in cusps in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, derivative

it's been a while since I've handled some math stuff and I'm a bit rusty, please be nice if I ask a stupid question.

Problem: I have n couples of lines, which are saved in memory as an array of 2D points, therefore no explicit functions. I have to check if the lines on couples are parallel, and this is a pretty easy task because it's sufficient to check if their derivatives are the same.

To do this in an algorithm, I have to check the slope of the line between two points of the function (which I have) and since I don't need an extreme accuracy, I can use the easy formula:

m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

But obviously this lead me to the big problem of x2 = x1. I can't give a default value for this case... how can I workaround it?

Comment: If x2 == x1 then the slope is +/- INF depending on the sign of y2 - y1.

Comment: What is the type of `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and  `y2`? What should the default behaviour be? May it be infinity?

Comment: @stefan x1, x2, y1, y2 are all double. I don't know what behaviour the algorithm should take in that case, if I could handle infinite it would be great 'cause I have to check if m1 ~ m2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to compare slopes in 2D is the following:

```
    m1 = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

    m2 = (y4-y3)/(x4-x3)

as m1 = m2


(y2-y1)*(x4-x3) = (y4-y3)*(x2-x1) if lines are parallel
```

This doesn't give divide by zero & is more efficient as it avoids floating point division.

Comment: Well, this is what I call an easy, efficient, smart, whatever solution.